# Collaborative Social Network Visualization

Tags: social-network-analysis

I do movement building work for Effective Altruism (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_altruism), and would like to level up our growth strategy. It occurred to me that a social network visualization tool which allowed us to strategically find and recruit new influencers/donors would be mega useful. I'd love to find something (preferably free), similar to InMaps, which would allow us to:

- Combine all of our social media connections into a single map
- Easily see who the superconnectors are
- Weight each person by their degree of social influence (perhaps some function of things like Klout score * amount of social media connections * number of Google mentions, etc)

Does such a thing exist? If not, is anyone interested in pro bono work for an amazing cause? =)

Disclaimer: I am a data science noob, so preferably the solution would be one with a nice GUI and minimal involvement of R or Python.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Gephi](https://gephi.github.io/), an open-source visualization tool, would help you a lot. Actually, as I know, the InMaps and its community detection algorithm are same as the Gephi's.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to build your graph from raw data without using at least basic programming skills. I'm not aware of a drag-and-drop interface for importing and displaying data. Graphs are just a bit too complex. Imagine trying to find the profit of selling a product if all you had was CSVs of receipts dropped into Excel. You'd need labels of the columns, some basic calculations, and so on before you had anything intelligible. Graphs are similar in this regard.

Thankfully, there are open source solutions, with some elbow grease and a few days of work, you can probably get a nice visualization.

Cypher queries are relatively simple to write. Using Neo4j and Cypher, you can create a basic visualization of your graph, which is displayed using D3.js

GraphAlchemist recently open-sourced their project Alchemy.js which specializes in graph visualization. https://github.com/GraphAlchemist/Alchemy

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfect solution to this. You can try any of these tools for achieving the particular functionality

- [Giphy](http://giphy.com/)
  *(Simple and open source)*
- [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/) *(More interactive visualization but paid. Trial availble)*

Hope it helps!